# Updating or inserting high scores in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been racking my brain over this for the past few days and I'm not sure it's possible, but figured I ask here.

Is it possible for a single SQL statement to update a high score if your score is greater or insert it if your first score?

My Score table has a UserID, Level and Score columns and I like it to follow the following logic:

- If your new score is greater than your last score for this Level, then replace it.
- If you don't have a score for this Level then add it.
- If your score for this Level is less than your highest score for this Level then do nothing.

Is this possible in a single SQL statement or do I have to use two, one to see if you have a new high score and if so, replace it?  Each UserID would have only one score in the table for each Level.

I'm using MySQL.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer below, this following SQL worked:

```
INSERT INTO Scores SET UserID = 'user', Level = 'level', Score = 'score'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score = IF (Score < 'score', 'score', Score)
```

My table is defined so UserID and Level are both keys.

Comment: I don't have any of them anymore, but mostly trying to use REPLACE INTO with a WHERE clause, but that doesn't seem to be syntactically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for this

This [site](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/1/18/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql) shows the use of `IF` statements instead of `WHERE` to accomplish your only updating the score if higher.

```
INSERT INTO Scores
SET UserID = 'user'
   , Level = 'level'
   , Score = 'score'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   Score = IF (Score < 'score', 'score', Score)
```

Comment: I thought about that, but that only works correctly if there is just one unique index / primary key. Since the rows need to be keyed by user id AND level, i'm not sure if it can work.

Comment: @BrianGlaz What is your key for the table?

Comment: I'm not the OP =p. The documentation says that if the table has two unique / primary indexes, insert on duplicate key update queries them using OR. This will cause problems because it could update a different users score, or the wrong level for the correct user.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Sorry, didn't read the name clearly.  From what I understood the documentation to say, if there is a `Unique Index` on  UserId and Level together, this should work.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work because you can't use a WHERE clause, so I can't update it only if the new score is higher than the last one.  Unless I'm using it wrong.  BTW, my table has two keys, one for UserID and Level.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat You can use `IF` statements, and I have updated my answer to provide a link to an example.

Comment: @AdamWenger yeah, I suppose a combined unique index would do the trick. Roger, you should be abele to use an `IF` function in the update section to get it to work... something like this maybe `IF(new_score > old_score, new_score, old_score)`

Comment: OK, using the IF function worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need two statements, sorry. Some people are going to suggest `REPLACE INTO`, but this will not solve your problem, because `REPLACE INTO` will delete the row before adding it again (if it exists). Therefore, you will lose the original score. You won't be able to increment the score using `REPLACE INTO`.

Edit: That is, if you don't already have the score in memory. But I don't recommend doing incrementing operations by selecting data into application memory, incrementing it, then updating the table because you could inadvertently cause a race condition this way.

Edit #2: Actually [the guy above me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287610/430634) just linked to some functionality I wasn't aware of. If you're using unique keys, this will work for you.